# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, import, angular, ionic2

I know this question already asked but there is not any solution for that so i raised this issue again

I want store data locally in hybrid app so i used SqlStorage db. On platform ready event i tried to just insert dumy data.

When i evalute my code in chrome console i getting error.
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

code that i used

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';
import {LoginTabPage} from './pages/login-tab/login-tab';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {WebService} from './services/webservice';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {DatabaseHelper} from './services/DatabaseHelper';
import {Storage, SqlStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = LoginTabPage;
  //public db: SQLite;
  db : DatabaseHelper;
  storage: Storage = null;


  constructor(platform: Platform) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
            this.db = new DatabaseHelper();
            let options = {
              name: '_Novity',              // the name of the database
              backupFlag: SqlStorage.BACKUP_LOCAL, // where to store the file
              existingDatabase: false              // load this as an existing database
            };
            this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage, options);
                this.db.createMemberTable();
            this.db.createLoginTable();

            var sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + this.db.sqtable_UserInfo + ' ( '+this.db.COLUMN_userId +' , '+ this.db.COLUMN_password + ' ) VALUES ( ?, ?)';
            this.storage.query(sql, ['varshil','shah']).then((res) => {
                  console.log(res);
              }, (err) => {
                  console.log('Error: ', err.res);
              });
        });
  }
}
enableProdMode();
ionicBootstrap(MyApp,[WebService]);

public createLoginTable()
    {

       this.storage.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+ this.sqtable_UserInfo +' ( '+ this.COLUMN_userId +' TEXT, '+ this.COLUMN_password +' TEXT)');
    }
```

**When i run above code that throw Undefined error in query**